# Model mean/median change per observation time?

Tags: time-series, cox-model, observational-study

A Cox proportional hazards model makes it possible to investigate how an independent variable affects the risk of a dichotomous state occurring per observation time.

Is it possible to model (A Cox proportional hazards model would not be appropriate for this) how an independent variable affects the mean/median change of a continuous value per observation time?

This question is not based on any data that I have possession of at the moment, but I spent some time designing a fitting R dataset:

```
df.test2 <- data.frame(
  "id" = sample(1:10000, 10000),
  "exercise.hpday" = runif(10000, 0, 3),
  "food.kcalpday" = runif(10000, 1300, 3800),
  "time.days" = rep(NA, 10000),
  "weightchange.kg" = rep(NA, 10000),
  "weightchange.5kgormore" = rep(NA, 10000))

df.test2$weightchange.kg <- runif(10000, -5, 5)
df.test2$weightchange.kg[df.test2$food.kcalpday > quantile(df.test2$food.kcalpday)["75%"]] <- runif(2500, -5, 20)
df.test2$weightchange.kg[df.test2$food.kcalpday < quantile(df.test2$food.kcalpday)["25%"]] <- runif(2500, -20, 5)
df.test2$weightchange.5kgincr <- df.test2$weightchange.kg >= 5

prob <- c(rep(0.5/182, 182), rep(2/183, 183)) #individuals with larger weight changes were observed for longer
df.test2$time.days <- sample(1:365, 10000, replace=T)
df.test2$time.days[df.test2$food.kcalpday > quantile(df.test2$food.kcalpday)["75%"]] <- sample(1:365, 2500, replace=T, prob)
df.test2$time.days[df.test2$food.kcalpday < quantile(df.test2$food.kcalpday)["25%"]] <- sample(1:365, 2500, replace=T, prob)

library(survival) 
summary(coxph(Surv(df.test2$time.days, df.test2$weightchange.5kgincr) ~ food.kcalpday, data = df.test2))
#A high food.kcalpday leads to more weightchange.5kgincr per time.days

#Is it possible to model how food.kcalpday affects weightchange.kg per time.days?
```

Comment: The Cox model models time-time event (yes/no). Event status is dichotomous. Are your referring to a continuous event status?

Comment: Yes, that would be one way of putting it I guess. A continuous event status is not possible in a Cox model as far as I know, so I chose to describe it like I did above.

Comment: The Cox model can only be used for dichotomous event status. It's unclear to me from your question whether you are trying to use the Cox model for "continuous" event status or whether you seek advice regarding other models capable of your analytic task. Providing a small sample of data would be helpful and increase your chances of obtaining an answer.

Comment: I am seeking an other model for my analytic task. I added a clarification and an example to the main question based on your comment

Comment: I believe you are confusing time to event with the effect of time. Look up “repeated measures analysis” or “time series analysis.”